# Conditional selection in sublist using Select in Mathematica

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

Considering the following List :

```
answers = {
          {{1, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {6, 4}}, 
          {{2, 1}, {2, 8}}, {{2,3}, {8, 2}}, 
          {{3, 1}, {1, 9}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 7}}
          }
```

[image]

Within the context of a task where subjects are sequentially presented 2 stimuli, having to choose the one they prefer, the first sublist :

```
{{1, 2}, {7, 3}}
```

can be read as

{{Cond1,Cond2}, {Cond1 Preferred Count,Cond2 Preferred Count}}

So when choosing 10 times between Cond1 & Cond2 when Cond1 is presented first, Cond1 is preferred 7 times out of 10.

**

> I need to conditionally extract and/or
>   sum part of the list.

**

What I have been doing thus far:

To extract lists where Cond1 is presented first :

```
Select[answers, #[[1, 1]] == 1 &]
```

= {{{1, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {6, 4}}}

And to get the total of count for one condition against all others :

```
Plus @@ Select[answers, #[[1, 1]] == 1 &][[All, 2]]
```

={13, 7}

**Now, I need to :**

**Query the total count for Cond1 VS Cond2 & Cond2 VS Cond1 :**

`{{{1, 2}, {7, 3}},{{2, 1}, {2, 8}}}`

would be the output

**or total of count when Cond2 was presented first against Cond3 :**

`{{2,3}, {8, 2}}`

**Those are what I am missing.
There are 5 conditions total in reality**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like `Cases` for this, since I think the syntax comes out cleaner.  Here's one approach, using a couple of light utility functions:

```
In[25]:= conditions[pat_] := Cases[answers, {pat, _}]

In[26]:= conditionSums[pat_] := Total[Last /@ conditions[pat]]

In[27]:= conditions[{1, _}]

Out[27]= {{{1, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {6, 4}}}

In[28]:= conditionSums[{1, _}]

Out[28]= {13, 7}

In[29]:= conditions[{1, 2} | {2, 1}]

Out[29]= {{{1, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 8}}}

In[30]:= conditions[{2, 3}]

Out[30]= {{{2, 3}, {8, 2}}}
```

Comment: Brett, thank You very much, I like this very much, so clear. First time I will use Patterns !